# problem in display in a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

**as you see in the screen prints, tableView always displays a single value in the tableView "Title" My problem is to display all the array values ​​detailTableView**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSArray* tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Titre", @"Nom", @"Prenon",@"Adresse",@"Phone",@"Mobile",@"Mail",@"Site",@"Note",nil];
self.detailsTableView = tmpArray;
[tmpArray release];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

---

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text =[self.detailsTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;    
return cell;
```

}
[image]

Comment: Try putting cell.textLabel.text into the if clause. Also, try making cellIdentifier unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screen grab, it looks like you've only got one cell per section.  In which case you need to use indexPath.section instead of indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

From the apple Documentation

**textLabel**

Returns the label used for the main textual content of the table cell. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *textLabel
```

**Discussion**

Holds the main label of the cell. UITableViewCell **adds an appropriate label** when you create the cell in a given cell style. See “Cell Styles” for descriptions of the main label in currently defined cell styles.

So Create a new `UILabel` and add it to `textLabel`

Answer (score 0):

did you set as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    {

return [self.detailsTableView count];
}
```